# Scrolling Up/Down with a keyboard shortcut

Tags: mouse, scrolling

I have a scroll wheel that doesn't work and don't really wanna buy a new mouse, on windows there was a way to make this happen, I was wondering if there is a way I can setup a keyboard shortcut to scroll up/down.

Thank you!

Comment: You can setup shortcuts in the keyboard section of the settings program.

Comment: arrow up/down and page up/down keys don't work for you ?

Comment: I'm looking for the same, and arrow keys and pgup/pgdown do not quit cut it: in a text editor, arrow keys only move the view when the cursor finally reaches the top/bottom of the text, and pgup/pgdown make to large jumps.